# Не записывается результат после возврата из функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Я делаю лабораторную работу. Задача - распараллелить вычисление интеграла на 4 потока. 
Проблема возникла с результатом работы функции `DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(void *d)`. Результат записывается в указатель. Внутри функции он есть, и в указатель записывается, но вне функции его уже нет. В чем тут ошибка?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <thread>

#define NUMPOINT 10000000
using namespace std;

struct Integral {
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    double value = 0;
};

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(void *d){
    double step = 0, borders = 0, curX = 0, result = 0;

    Integral *data = (Integral*)d;
    step = (data->b - data->a) / NUMPOINT;
    borders = (cos(data->a) + cos(data->b))/2;
    curX = data->a;

    while(curX <= data->b) {
        curX += step;
        result += cos(curX);
    }
    result = step * (result + borders);
    data->value = result;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a = 1, b = 2;
    double value = 0;
    SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);
    int cpuCount = siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    HANDLE *hThreads = new HANDLE[cpuCount];
    Integral *integrals = new Integral[cpuCount];
    double range = (b - a) / cpuCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++)
    {
        integrals[i].a = i * range + a;
        integrals[i].b = i * range + range + a;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc, &integrals[i], 0, NULL);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(cpuCount, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
        //value += integrals[i].value;
        cout << integrals[i].value << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение, возвращаемое `CreateThread` (дескриптор созданного потока), никак не используется, массив `hThreads` содержит мусор. Соответственно `WaitForMultipleObjects` не ожидает завершения потоков (возвращаемое значение тоже следует проверять). Дескрипторы потоков затем необходимо освобождать вызовом `CloseHandle` (и, опять же, проверять возвращаемое значение).